# Textmate: Increase / Decrease The Selection?

Tags: textmate, textselection

Does anyone know of a bundle/plugin/keyboard command to increase the scope of selected text?

Intellij (and I think Eclipse) allow you to increase the scope of your selection.  Intellij will do this if you place the cursor on a method name, for example, press option + Up Arrow.  doing that would select the full method name.  Option + Up Arrow again would select the method name *and* the object name.  Here's what I mean:

1. Nothing selected, but cursor in the method name:  myObject.doSomething()
2. Option Up Arrow:  myObject.**doSomething()**
3. Option Up Arrow again:  **myObject.doSomething()**

Option down arrow will decrease the scope of the selection -- the inverse of the above.

This functionality will go from the method name, to the object, to the line, to the entire method, and so on.  it's very handy tool, you must admit.

I know that shift + option + right/left arrow will select text, but it won't do it with scope in mind.  Have I been missing something obvious with TextMate all these years, or does this need to be added on an upcoming version?

Thanks!